# Change UI based on change to provided value

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-navigation

I have a screen from which I want to navigate to a new screen if a provided boolean value(isLoggedIn) gets changed to true. The first build method below **is not possible** since Navigator cannot be called during build. I attempted to do this in build because I need access to context to use my provider. The value of isLoggedIn coming from the provider of Authorization can potentially change at any time, so I would have to check for this.

How can I solve this using provider and navigator?

```
//Not working solution
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Authorization auth = Provider.of<Authorization>(context);
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
        child: auth.isLoggedIn
            ? Text(
                "Logged In",
              )
            : Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'sign-in')),
  );
}
```

I can do it without Navigator like this:

```
//Working solution
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = 'splash';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final auth = Provider.of<Authorization>(context);
    return auth.isLoggedIn ? HomeScreen() : SignInScreen();
  }
}
```

But I do not now if that is a solid approach.

Comment: You are mixing UI code with functional code. You can't do this. That if should be outside of the build method. You should check if the user is logged in and then navigate to another view, or if the user is not logged in, navigate to the login page.

Comment: I know that I have to remove navigator outside of the build method as I state in the question. Since I don't know when the provided value changes where will you place this check?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach to solving your problem.

```
enum AuthStatus {
  NOT_DETERMINED,
  NOT_LOGGED_IN,
  LOGGED_IN,
}//Always define this outside the class.


 AuthStatus authStatus = AuthStatus.NOT_DETERMINED;
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser().then((user) {
      setState(() {
        if (user != null) {
          _userId = user?.uid;
         
        }
        authStatus =
            user?.uid == null ? AuthStatus.NOT_LOGGED_IN : AuthStatus.LOGGED_IN;
      });
    });
  }
Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser() async {
FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
return user;
}

  void loginCallback() {
    getCurrentUser().then((user) {
      setState(() {
        _userId = user.uid.toString();
         authStatus = AuthStatus.LOGGED_IN;
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/');
              });
    });
  }
   
   Widget buildWaitingScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                radius: 70.0,
                child: Image.asset('assets/icons/icon.png'),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (authStatus) {
      case AuthStatus.NOT_DETERMINED:
        return buildWaitingScreen();
        break;
      case AuthStatus.NOT_LOGGED_IN:
        return new LoginSignUpPage();
        break;
      case AuthStatus.LOGGED_IN:
        if (_userId.length > 0 && _userId != null) {
          return new HomePage();
        } else
          return buildWaitingScreen();
        break;
      default:
        return buildWaitingScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

To navigate use this in initState

```
 void loginCallback() {
  getCurrentUser().then((user) {
  setState(() {
    _userId = user.uid.toString();
     authStatus = AuthStatus.LOGGED_IN;
           });}); 
   if(authStatus==AuthStatus.LOGGED_IN){
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'sign-in')} }
```

Comment: It using navigator not a recommended approach. Should I instead return the screen needed based on the change in the provided auth boolean? 
@João Soares wouldn't you also consider this a mix of UI code with functional code this here is still being checked for the value in the build method?

Comment: This is just an example of the approach.  This is designed to help you keep a user logged in. that way if you close the app you don't have to log in again. There is another option: loginCallback() in my code can be called in initState to Navigate the user if logged in else build the main context

Comment: Okay, in my case where I rely on BuildContext to get my auth from my provider I cannot do it in initstate. Further, in your case, can initState check for dynamic changes to AuthStatus? Or is it only initially when initState is called this is checked?